# Unable to bind to ios table section cells in mvvmcross, child cells bind as expected

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create a TableView with grouped sections like so:

[image: TableView with sections]

I am binding a list of groups to the table. A group contains a few string properties and a list of items, while an item contains some string properties as well. The group and item cells each have their own class which extends `MvxTableViewCell`.

Inside the class for each the cells I am binding as follows:

The item cell:

```
 this.DelayBind(() =>
                {
                    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ItemCellView, ItemCellViewModel>();
                    set.Bind(lblOne).To(item=> item.propertyOne);
                    set.Apply();
                });
```

And the group cell:

```
this.DelayBind(() =>
                    {
                        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<GroupCellView, GroupCellViewModel>();
                        set.Bind(lblOne).To(group=> group.propertyOne);
                        set.Apply();
                    });
```

My TableSource in the main view extends `MvxStandardTableViewSource` and uses the overridden methods to get the respective cells for the table. `public override UIView GetViewForHeader` returns a group cell view while `protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor` returns an item cell view.

My problem is that the group view cell does not bind whatsoever while the item view cell binds just fine even though I see no discernible difference between the two. The group view cell is being constructed however, it's just the binding that is not taking place inside the cell.

Edit: Added the table view source:

```
private class TableSource : MvxStandardTableViewSource
        {
            private List<GroupCellViewModel> _groups;
            public new List<GroupCellViewModel> ItemsSource
            {
                get
                {
                    return _groups;
                }
                set
                {
                    _groups = value;
                    ReloadTableData();
                }
            }

            public TableSource(UITableView tableView)
                : base(tableView)
            {
            }

            public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, int group)
            {
                if (_groups == null)
                    return string.Empty;

                return Utils.FormatDate(_groups[group].Date);
            }

            public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, int group)
            {
                return MakeHeaderRow(tableView, _groups[group]);
            }

            public override float GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, int section)
            {
                return 50;
            }

            public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                return 50;
            }

            public override int NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
            {
                if (_groups == null)
                    return 0;

                return _groups.Count;
            }

            public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int group)
            {
                if (_groups == null)
                    return 0;

                return _groups[group].Items.Count;
            }

            protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
            {
                UITableViewCell cell;
                if (item is Item)
                {
                    cell = MakeItemRow(tableView, (Item)item);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unknown cell type " + item.GetType().Name);
                }

                return cell;
            }

            protected override object GetItemAt(NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                if (_groups == null)
                    return null;

                return _groups[indexPath.Section].Items[indexPath.Row];
            }

            private UITableViewCell MakeHeaderRow(UITableView tableView, GroupCellViewModel group)
            {
                var existing = (GroupCellView)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(GroupCellView.Key);
                if (existing != null)
                    return existing;

                return new GroupCellView();
            }

            private UITableViewCell MakeItemRow(UITableView tableView, Item item)
            {
                var existing = (ItemCellView)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ItemCellView.Key);
                if (existing != null)
                    return existing;

                return new ItemCellView();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your TableViewSource as well?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Just modified the post an added it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your solution is almost there - but you'll need to provide a `GetViewForHeader` implementation which is a bit more like the binding `GetCell` implementation which MvvmCross provides - note the `DataContext` setting in:

```
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var item = GetItemAt(indexPath);
        var cell = GetOrCreateCellFor(tableView, indexPath, item);

        var bindable = cell as IMvxDataConsumer;
        if (bindable != null)
            bindable.DataContext = item;

        return cell;
    }
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxBaseTableViewSource.cs#L97

For the header, you'll need to set the `DataContext` to the appropriate "view model" for the group header.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I'm curious as to why the data context has to be manually set for the header rows and not the regular rows though?